# Value not sticking in return value for a list (C#)

Tags: c#, list, function

There is probably a simple answer but while practicing some questions on hacker rank the "aScore" isn't saying at a certain value, the first value in `a[i]` is greater than `b[i]`. I've been trying to debug the code but I can't print what I want to the console on hacker rank, it's forced to come out to the answer's output somehow.

```
public static List<int> compareTriplets(List<int> a, List<int> b)
{
    int aScore=0;
    for(int i=0; i ==(a.Count-1);i++)
    if (a[i]>b[i]){
        aScore++;
    }
    return new List<int>(){aScore,1} ;   
    }
```

}

[image: Code Output]

Comment: At a guess: you misunderstood the task. You have N items in a, N items in b, and you need to return a list of N items.

Comment: We don't know what this code is trying to achieve, or what the input is, which makes it very hard to help here. (I'd also strongly suggest reformatting the code, and always using braces for `for` statements etc.)

Comment: Basically the first in second value are 'scores' each time a[i] is bigger than b[i] or vice versa, the score is incremented by one.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i ==(a.Count-1);i++)` try `for(int i=0; i < a.Count; i++)` instead. `for` will iterate as long as the condition ( second "part" ) resolves to `true`.

Comment: @Fildor that fixed it, thanks! I guess you can't use == in for loops.

Comment: You can, as long as it makes the continue-condition pass when it should. Which it did not in your case.

Comment: @Fildor Oh wow. I'm ridiculous, I'm just seeing that now. Thanks for the help

Comment: @zjbrown it is that you just need to understand the different parts of the `for` loop. It is `for(initial_state; condition_to_keep_looping; action_after_each_iteration)`. Edit: Looks like you just got it ;-)

Comment: _"Oh wow. I'm ridiculous"_ - meh. I am pretty confident in saying that _every_ programmer in "C-like" languages (including java) fell for this at least once. (yes, that includes myself ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for(int i=0; i ==(a.Count-1);i++)` should be `for(int i=0; i < a.Count; i++)`

The for loop executes and iterates as long as the condition (second "part") resolves to true.

In your original code, it does not: 0 does not equal a.Count-1, so the loop body is not executed even once.